# text-overflow:ellipsis; Can't get to work

Tags: css

Usually I accomplish this with PHP or JS if I needed to, but I'm trying to make this design responsive and for the life of me I cannot get the 3 dots to show up at the end of the cutoff string. Here's what I'm doing:

```
<article class="aBlogCont">
    <h2><time class="aBlogDate" pubdate="pudate">12/18/13</time> : Welcome</h2>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
    <hr />
</article>
```

And My CSS:

```
.aBlogCont{
    width:29.33%;
    padding-left:2%;
    padding-right:2%;
    height:350px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
.aBlogCont > p{
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

From what I've read, this is correct. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/335F6/ Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: From MDN: `text-overflow` only affects content that is overflowing a block container element in its inline progression direction (not text overflowing at the bottom of a box, for example). Text can overflow when it is prevented from wrapping (e.g., due to `white-space:nowrap`) or a single word being too long to fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `white-space: nowrap` should fix it:

```
.aBlogCont > p{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/335F6/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding white-space:nowrap; to .aBlogCont